# How to diff free users and premium users who has subscribed for the app from istore

Tags: cordova, ios6, itunes

I have created an Hybrid app using HTML5, JQuery & AJAX for dynamically loading the contents, and i have used phone gap to create package that is ready to upload on istore.Our app will be sold in the App Store "for free" with access to 60% of the content. If the user wants to add additional chapters he must be able to use the "in-app-purchase" option.

My Question is how control the app? Basically i need to diff between the users who has premium acces and load the page with full contents for them.

Please guide me through the steps i need to follow.

Comment: Please help me out with the in-app-purchase!!!!

Answer (score 0):

If you are targeting iOS and want to use the Apple App Store in-app purchasing, then you will need to use a [plugin](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/InAppPurchaseManager).

In-app purchasing sounds like a complicated beast so you may wish to learn how it works before tackling it. The following is a good walkthrough: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, Currently i created an hybrid app in windows. Is there any other work around that i could use which is compatible with phonegap for making any purchase online.

Comment: There are lots, including rolling your own and using PayPal or something, however, everything apart from the official Apple scheme will fall foul of Apple's T&C for publishing an App to their App Store AFAIK.